# Вывод элементов интерфейса в зависимости от условия + storyboards

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone, objective-c

Добрый день, подскажите, как выводить разные наборы элементов интерфейса, в зависимости от условия, с использванием storyboards?

Есть необходимость показывать разные контролы, в зависимости от состояния segmented controls. Но я не понял как при использовании storyboards реализовать что-то подобное.

Пример:
https://www.monosnap.com/image/tfqvSshn6e3vTjawrbv6RxhQD.png

Answer (score 1):

На сториборде делаете несколько `scene` с вариантами. От "главной" сцены протягиваете `segue'`и от того от чего будете инициировать переход (кнопка, ячейка `tableView` и тд) на сцены с вариантами. Выделив segue задайте каждому из них уникальный `identifier`: http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Segue-identifier.png

там где у Вас меняется условие делайте следующее:

```
if (// условие1)
{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstSegue" sender:self];
}
if (// условие2)
{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Тогда встает вопрос с возвратом к основной сцене. Получается надо делать еще segue от каждой "второстепенной" сцены обратно?

Comment: Если иерархия контроллеров работает без navigationController'a (как показано на Вашей схеме) то да, накладываете на  сцены вариантов navbar, на него бросаете кнопку и тянете push-сегвей назад на основной контроллер

Comment: Это похоже на костыль :)

Comment: Это модальное представление. Если хотите иерархию контроллеров - задайте основному контроллеру navigationController - и тогда будете двигаться по нему. http://easyplace.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/viewcontrollers.png